# Vote Results Zero

Tags: views, theming

I am fairly new to this drupal and I can't seem to get the rate widget integrated into [views](https://drupal.org/project/views) so i can output a chart on my custom page. I set up the relation to "vote results" and set to the the custom widget I created on rate. I have tried every option the field "vote results" is zero. My configuration is as follows:

Rate widget:
name: Reviews
tag: vote_tag
type: options

Views:
Relation Filter: Vote Results
tag: vote_tag
aggression: Number of votes

Fields:
Vote results: value
Vote: value

the vote results gives me a zero and also how can I print out the label of the option rather than than value. It is display correctly in results page of the node but I can't print a chart using that data or integrate into view

Answer (score 0):

VotingAPI module provides an API for other modules to cast votes on any entity. There are many modules that support VotingAPI, such as FiveStar, Rate, etc.

Making use of VotingAPI actually depends on your approach.

FiveStar module, for example, does NOT save data to VotingAPI-related in certain widgets. First, you need to make sure you are actually recording values to VotingAPI. Fivestar module requires VotingAPI by default, but does not use it for these widgets.

([img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvEFX.png))
[image: rated while viewing]

If you are using some other module or unsure, check `votingapi_vote` table to see if there are actual data in the table.

In Views, the relationship's configuration is *very* important.

- **Value type**: Points
- **Vote tag**: (choose the tag)
- **Aggregation function**: Number of votes

Comment: I am using rate module and set my settings to options in the rate widget but when i come to views and set to option the results show up zero